# Android: Is there an "external" shared storage?

Tags: android, storage, persistence

in the Android documentation related to persistence there is a way to access and write to internal and external storage in the app-specific storage guide. I wonder if this also applies to shared storage.

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lyaQYDN7wkIJ:https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231411/why-do-people-consider-mobiles-inbuilt-memory-as-internal-storage-and-sd-cards

Comment: Yes it applies.